# Devise confirmation email always to the admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-confirmable

I'm building a system using Devise as the gem responsible for handling users.

What I'm looking for it's a way to send the confirmation email always to the same email(it would be the admin), so that he can choose if the person should, or not, be allowed into the system.

Comment: The [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki) has several articles on how to create closed systems. As written this question is far too broad and would require a lengthy tutorial to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [How To](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in) to let admin confirm the user before signin, you probably won't need `comfirmable` module.